# ng-admin doesn't initialize in another ui-view

Tags: angular-ui-router, ng-admin

I have faced a problem that `ng-admin` is not rendering inside simple `ui-view`.

Here is the code:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: homeTemplate
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        template: loginTemplate,
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .state('register', {
        url: "/register",
        template: "<div>Register is under maintenance</div>",
    })
;
```

And here is Html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Admin-tool</title>
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />-->
</head>
<body ng-strict-di class="main-content">

    <div id="content-body" class="content">

        <div ui-view=""></div>

    </div>

    <pg-footer></pg-footer>

</body>
```

Also there is an info message

> WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

Maybe this is the case? Could you please point me out why it doesn't even render `ng-admin` simple page?

In browser it just looks like:

```
<!-- uiView: -->
<div ui-view="" class="ng-scope"></div>
```

Comment: Which version of angular/ui-router?

Comment: And also please post more code. What is homeTemplate in reference to? A file path, or a specific html template string?

Comment: homeTemplate is just simple as '<div ui-view="ng-admin"></div>' As for version - angular is 1.4.12, and router "latest"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ng-admin has it's own routing so it was needed to make login rout and default on which ng-admin initialize. If it's needed to make custom pages inside ng-admin you just need to specify that in your state like this: `parent: 'ng-admin'`